# Make a data frame of two columns based on values less than a threshold value in column 2 in r

Tags: r, dataframe, max, threshold

I want to make a data frame that only has entries below a certain defined threshold that is compared with column b, such that entry "OP2775iib SAV OP2958i_b POR" is excluded.

I tried this code:

```
less_than_threshold <- data.frame(which(data[data$b < threshold]))
```

but it returns and error that I cant quite grasp:

Error in `[.data.frame`(pairwise_ind_Mdists, pairwise_ind_Mdists$Mdist <  : 
  undefined columns selected

This is a sample of the data I'm working with:

```
data <- data.frame(a = c("OP2775iia MOU OP2775iib SAV","OP2775iia MOU OP2958i_a COM","OP2775iib SAV OP2958i_a COM","OP2775iia MOU OP2958i_b POR","OP2775iib SAV OP2958i_b POR"),
                           b = c(4.9022276,3.8867063,3.0126033,5.0261763,6.3745697))

threshold <- 6.3745697
```

I want a data frame that has all the entries from the original dataset except for the last entry "OP2775iib SAV OP2958i_b POR"

Comment: `data[data$b < threshold,]` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest dplyr package

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  filter(b < threshold)

                            a        b
1 OP2775iia MOU OP2775iib SAV 4.902228
2 OP2775iia MOU OP2958i_a COM 3.886706
3 OP2775iib SAV OP2958i_a COM 3.012603
4 OP2775iia MOU OP2958i_b POR 5.026176
```